# strings within tuples python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, tuples, substring

Seeking advice on a particularly irksome challenge I'm dealing with right now while learning python 3.x. Where it wants me to take in a string, then output it into 4 separate substrings within a tuple in different formats. UPPER CASE / lower case / Title Case / and esac esrever(reverse case).

```
def stringcases(str):

    str = "bob frank tim john jill"
    reverse = ''

    uppercase = str.upper()
    lowercase = str.lower()
    single_word = str.split()
    titlecase = (' '.join((word.capitalize() for word in single_word)))
    for l in str:
        reverse = l + reverse
    cv = uppercase, lowercase, titlecase, reverse
    convergence = tuple(cv)

    return convergence
```

So the first time I misunderstood it and wound up returning a tuple containing 4 tuples of each challenge parameter, after fixing it I still seem to be up against a wall. Now I know it could just be something I'm not meeting within the particular challenge, but I figured it better to ask and see if I'm doing it wrong and why, because right now the output looks like what I thought it should for a tuple containing 4 substrings, with them all in the prescribed format.

The output looks like so.

```
('BOB FRANK TIM JOHN JILL', 'bob frank tim john jill', 'Bob Frank Tim John Jill', 'llij nhoj mit knarf bob')
```

Am I doing it wrong? If so what'd I miss / am missing.

Comment: It's strange that your function does not use its only parameter at all. You override the value passed as an argument immediately.

Comment: Yea, I was actually wasn't even thinking about that, which I believe was the entire hangup, probably a big part of why I was having so much trouble coming to the solution. I mean, from what I can see my output was correct, but the use input from the test was being overwritten by my fixed input, thus nullifying things for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the function below.

```
def stringcases(input_string):
    uppercase = input_string.upper()
    lowercase = input_string.lower()
    single_word = input_string.split()
    titlecase = (' '.join((word.capitalize() for word in single_word)))
    reverse = input_string[::-1]
    cv = (uppercase, lowercase, titlecase, reverse)
    return cv
```

The first thing that you need to change is the variable name. You are using `str` as your input variable. Do not do that. `str` is a native python class. Refrain from overwriting it.

The second thing that you should remove from your function is this line

```
str = "bob frank tim john jill"
```

You are already taking a user input. Use that instead of overwriting it with a fixed input. In your function, no matter what input string you put, you'll get the same output.

Lastly, to take the reverse of a string, you can simply do the following

```
>>> 'abc'[::-1]
'cba'
```

You don't need the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Clock_Slave, that fixed input I thought would get overwritten by whatever the test used for input, obviously that was wrong because I completely spaced on making the input fixed, and wasn't connecting the dots when the output was finally coming out right, but the road to get there within the code was wrong where you pointed out.

Also thanks for the other tips, I want to write efficient code so finding out where I can write less to achieve the same results like the string reversal is awesome.